# Why do I get "I don't deserve this" when attempting to relocate?

Tags: state-of-decay

I finished the mission where Lilly's little brother takes me to all of these bases, and so I tried to relocate. However it says 'I don't deserve this'

Why does it say that and how can I relocate then?

Comment: Did you have 100 influence when attempting to relocate? See "[How can I make a new home base?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/132801/4797)" -  for more info