# Cant make McReady Farmhouse a Home

Tags: state-of-decay

I go to the McReady Farmhouse to try and make a new home site. I have nine population, 334 influence, and 53 materials. When I click the button to make it a home site, I'm told "no".

I have completed the mission Home Away From Home.

Comment: What exactly do they say? I'm sure it's not just "no". You should need 8 people and 30 materials, so you should be fine. That house is terrible anyway, FYI.

Comment: They say things like "maybe not" and "that work"

Comment: They would say that stuff if you're on a mission.

Comment: Related: [How can I make a new home base?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/132801/4797)

Answer (score 3):

In order to settle [a home site](http://stateofdecay.wikia.com/wiki/Home_Sites) during the main story, you need to meet several criteria:

1. Have completed the mission Home Away From Home
2. Not currently on a mission
3. Have enough people
4. Have enough resources
5. Have enough influence
6. Do not already have more outposts than the new home site can support

According to your statements, you've satisfied most of these: You already did the quest. The [McReady Farmhouse](http://stateofdecay.wikia.com/wiki/McReady_Farmhouse) requires 8 people and 30 materials, so you have that taken care of. Settling a new home site requires 100 influence, so you have that covered.

Therefore, check the other two.

Are you currently on a mission? If you're on a mission, you should normally have a blue objective somewhere on the map. Finish the mission, then try again.

The Farmhouse can support six outposts, so unless you already have more than six that shouldn't be a problem.

**Note on the Farmhouse**

Problems aside, I'd like to point out that the McReady Farmhouse is a terrible homesite. You are vulnerable to attacks all the time, and have poor access to resources. The wiki article has this to say on the matter:

> Due to its remote location, it is impossible to create a safe area with Outposts around the farmhouse. The only building next to it, a barn, might provide some level of protection, but is ineffective against more than one horde. As a result, survivors living here are constantly threatened by zombies spawning literally a few steps away from the home site.

and

> In addition to the scarcity of scavenge spots, the area around the Farmhouse (Fields, Ochards, Houses and Warehouses surrounded by US Route 406) does not offer much in terms of resources and items variety. The only abundant resource is, not surprisingly, Food (which is abundant anywhere else in Trumbull Valley, anyway) and farming tools-turned-melee weapons.

and, finally

> Overall, the Farmhouse are more suitable for players looking for a challenge than those looking for a safe and practical home site to settle for a long period of time.

In my experience, the only home sites that are really any good are the Kirkman Residence, the Savini Residence, and the Snyder Trucking Warehouse.

Comment: @JeremyKLarsen No problem. If this solved your problem, please remember to mark it as accepted.